# PHPMyAdmin No longer Import Local SQL file?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I remember previous versions of PHPMyAdmin allowing me to import an SQL zip that I have already uploaded. I can't find this anywhere on version 3.4.10.1

I used to be able to simply provide the local path.

If they removed this it is one serious faux pas, especially since my SQL is 77MB which is over the 50MB upload limit within PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Nevermind, I downloaded an SQL splitter and uploaded my table in chunks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used an SQL splitter and uploaded the small chunks instead.